# How to connect orientdb with nativescript

Tags: nativescript

i'm using nativescript but can't connect database is orientdb. i try npm install orientjs https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs  but don't success. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

After have run the command: npm install orientjs

Save this code in a file.js:

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

 var server = OrientDB({
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 2424,
     username: 'root',
     password: 'root'
 });

 var db = server.use({
     name:  'GratefulDeadConcerts',
     username: 'root',
     password: 'root'
 });

 server.close();
```

**UPDATE**

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');

 var server = OrientDB({
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 2424,
     username: 'root',
     password: 'root'
 }).use({
     name:  'GratefulDeadConcerts',
     username: 'root',
     password: 'root'
 });

 server.close();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i had try it, but don't success

Comment: I've update my answer, could you try it? Let me know

Comment: How did you install orientjs?

Comment: npm i orientjs --save

Comment: Try to install orientjs running this command: npm install orientjs in Node.js command prompt, let me know

Comment: i think nativescript don't support npm(orientjs)